# How does air going through silica gel change its humidity

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, water, diffusion, humidity

Assume that the properties(temperature,humidity,velocity and so on) of the incoming air flow stay constant. The air flow goes through a silica gel plate. Humidity of the air will decrease, but how to calculate quantificationally?

I have searched the internet, only found theories to describe a steady state. Is there any dynamic model?